# Execute SQL Stored procedure in Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic

Below is the ASP page, onload of this page I need to execute a stored procedure. I need to pass a parameter into this stored procedure. The value for this parameter I am getting from the Session.  Stored procedure is supposed to insert a record into a table, and I don't need it to return any value back.
I can't get it to execute from the ASP page, no matter what I do. Please help.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
<% @Language=VBScript %>
<%Response.Buffer = true%>

<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<!--#include file = "connect.txt" -->    
<!--#include file= "adovbs.inc" -->

<%
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 

'this will be my parameter
Dim strID
strID = Session("ID")

ConnectionStr =       "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=***;Database=***;Uid=***;Pwd=***;"
conn.Open  ConnectionStr

With cmd
.ActiveConnection = conn
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.CommandText = "sp_Application_Insert"
.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@TUID ", adVarchar, adParamInput, 200, strID)
.Execute


End With
Set cmd = Nothing
conn.close 
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: People still write classic asp code?  Did Hurricane Matthew put us into a time warp?       I'm not trying to be mean.......this is dinosaur technology now.

Comment: @granadaCoder yes...some people still do. Of course some people are still using sql server 2000 (or even older). That doesn't mean it is a good thing. :)

Comment: Slight detour from the question. You really should avoid the sp_ prefix, or even better, avoid the prefix entirely. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly wrong in your code. Have you tried debugging to see what is actually happening? I know you can't step through it but add some response.write and response.end so you can see what is happening. Do you get an error?

Comment: And for the sake of everything sane you need to change the file extension on your connection include file as the txt extension is generally allowed on most sites. This means that is somebody gets a file listing your webserver will dutifully deliver that file an http attachment unless you have explicitly forbidden the txt extension as an allowed file type. Change it to .inc which is prohibited by default.

Comment: @granadaCoder unfortunately yes... the whole application is written in classic at where i work, its like 15 years old, and we can't re0write is it is right now.

Comment: Anyway, i removed the sp_ prefix, but it still doesn't execute. What else could be wrong? Am I passing the parameter correctly?

Comment: If you thought that removing the sp_ prefix would magically fix your code you obviously didn't read the article I posted. Again...have you tried debugging this? Error message? Does it even get to your line of code?

Comment: the problem is that i don't get any error. so i can't even tell what is wrong.

Comment: @SeanLange, I know i get to this line of code, I can Response.Write strID after it.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't execute? Have your run a profile session on your sql server? Is there a trigger on that table that maybe is silently rolling back the insert due to an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute SQL stored procedure using VBScript in a Classic ASP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795825/execute-sql-stored-procedure-using-vbscript-in-a-classic-asp-page)

Answer (score 1):

1. You should validate the parameter.....that it exists, and its a correct value for the expected datatype
2. You need some kind of error alert/logging.  Below is your code modified.
3. Mixing `ADODB.Connection` code (data layer) and html/asp (presentation layer) makes my eyes hurt.

the changes I made below are from

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/300043

```vb
<% @Language=VBScript %>
<%Response.Buffer = true%>

<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<!--#include file = "connect.txt" -->    
<!--#include file= "adovbs.inc" -->

<%
On Error Resume Next
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 

'this will be my parameter
Dim strID
strID = Session("ID")

ConnectionStr =       "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=***;Database=***;Uid=***;Pwd=***;"
conn.Open  ConnectionStr

With cmd
.ActiveConnection = conn
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.CommandText = "sp_Application_Insert"
.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@TUID ", adVarchar, adParamInput, 200, strID)
.Execute

if Err.Number <> 0 then

  Response.Write "An Error Has Occurred on this page!<BR>"
  Response.Write "The Error Number is: " & Err.number & "<BR>"
  Response.Write "The Description given is: " & Err.Description & "<BR>"

'' you can try the below too
'    Set objASPError = Server.GetLastError

 '   response.write "Category: " & objASPError.Category & _
  '   "ASPCode: " & objASPError.ASPCode & _
   '  "Number: " & objASPError.Number & _
    ' "ASPDescription: " & objASPError.ASPDescription & _
    ' "Description: " & objASPError.Description & _
    ' "Source: " & objASPError.Source

end if


End With
Set cmd = Nothing
conn.close 
%>

</body>
</html>
```

APPEND

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345484.aspx

```sql
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.sp_Application_Insert
    TO ***; /* where *** is your uid value in your connection string that you did not show */
```

Comment: thank you. I will not use the connection string in my code, when I finally get this proc to execute. Originally I just used con.Open, and i know it works because i can execute   con.Open
         rs.Open "SELECT ID_ID FROM Person where ix_National_ID = '" & strStudentID & "'", con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

Comment: Thank you for error code, i got the Permission denied to execute error. An Error Has Occurred on this page!
The Error Number is: -2147217911
The Description given is: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'Application_Insert', database 'DBName', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: Now you know what is wrong.See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345484.aspx

Comment: Thank you @granadaCoder, after setting the required permissions, the stored procedure finally executed.

Comment: SOF (StackOverFlow) etiquette is to mark an answer (the most helpful one) as "The Answer".  This way the question no longer shows up under the "Not Yet Answered" filtered-page.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set OBC = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
OBC.Open "connection_string"
S = "CALL sp_application_insert(5)"
OBC.Execute(S)
```

where connection_string := the ODBC connection string given as an ODBC source;
5 stands as an example for any numeric parameter. Taken from working ASP file.

Answer (score -1):

Final Code:

```
Dim strStudentID
Dim transactionId
strStudentID = Session("ix_National_ID")
transactionId = Session("transactionId")

Session("accesslevel") = ""
session("SessionStatus") = "5"




Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.command")
With cmd
.ActiveConnection = con
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.CommandText = "Temple_sp_Application_Insert"
.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@TUID ", adVarchar, adParamInput, 200, strStudentID)
.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@transactionId ", adVarchar,     adParamInput, 200, transactionId)
.Execute

if Err.Number <> 0 then

Response.Write "An Error Has Occurred on this page!<BR>"
Response.Write "The Error Number is: " & Err.number & "<BR>"
Response.Write "The Description given is: " & Err.Description & "<BR>"



end if


End With
Set cmd = Nothing
Set Con = Nothing

con.Close
```

I am getting the following error, note there is the Session variable (strStudentID)  at the end of the error description.

1. This error I get on the production server
   The Error Number is: -2147217911
   The Description given is: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]**915111111**
2. This error is on the non-production server. 
   The Error Number is: -2147217911
   The Description given is: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]915111111

Comment: strID <> strStudentID.