# SQL Server Error executing SQL stored procedure in ASP classic [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server] Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, asp-classic

Please see the SQL server error messages I am getting when executing a SQL Server stored procedure from ASP classic.

I am using two session variables as parameters for the stored procedure.

I had no issues with this, until just recently I started getting the following error, the errors are different between production and test servers.

Why is the Session variable appended to the error description, what does it mean?

Please see the code below and the errors.

```
Dim strStudentID
Dim transactionId
strStudentID = Session("ix_National_ID")
transactionId = Session("transactionId")

Session("accesslevel") = ""
session("SessionStatus") = "5"

Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.command")
With cmd
.ActiveConnection = con
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.CommandText = "Temple_sp_Application_Insert"
.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@TUID ", adVarchar, adParamInput, 200, strStudentID)
.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@transactionId ", adVarchar,     adParamInput, 200, transactionId)
.Execute

if Err.Number <> 0 then
  Response.Write "An Error Has Occurred on this page!<BR>"
  Response.Write "The Error Number is: " & Err.number & "<BR>"
  Response.Write "The Description given is: " & Err.Description & "<BR>"
end if

End With
Set cmd = Nothing
Set Con = Nothing

con.Close
```

I am getting the following error, note there is the Session variable (strStudentID)  at the end of the error description.

This error I get on the production server

> The Error Number is: -2147217911
>   The Description given is: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]915111111

This error is on the non-production server.

> The Error Number is: -2147217911
>   The Description given is: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]915111111

Comment: @marc_s I used code blocks for the formatting because it's output from the script, otherwise would have used a blockquote.

Comment: Related [A: Execute SQL Stored procedure in Classic ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39905617/692942).

Answer (score 2):

Well judging by the error

The error code refers to -2147217911 which is;

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]SELECT permission denied on object 'Table_Name', database 'Database_Name', owner 'dbo'.

On Microsoft Support Site there's is some more detail;

> <sup>From [Microsoft Support - KB963994](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/963994)</sup>
>   *The user's database login has not been granted the db_datareader role for the database.*

So you need to `GRANT` permission to the login you are using to call the Stored Procedure or one of the tables inside it, either way we'd need more information. For whatever reason your descriptions returned are pretty meaningless.

---

[Based on feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748533/sql-server-error-executing-sql-stored-procedure-in-asp-classic-microsoftsql-s/40748669#comment68723293_40748669)

I have no idea why the Session values are appended to the half completed error output, perhaps something else is getting added to the output in the Stored Procedure? Could be rogue `PRINT` statement for example.

Ideally we would need to see the Stored Procedure definition to rule that out.

Comment: Login that I am using to call the stored procedure, has all the appropriate permissions. The tables that are used by the stored proc are also permissioned. Anyway, why is the session variable at the end of the error description? [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]915111111

Comment: I am just trying to explain here, that all of the permissions were set properly, and the code was executing with no problems. All of a sudden I start getting this error now.

Comment: @Olesya The error code is `-2147217911` so as far as ADODB is concerned SQL Server is reporting a permissions issue somewhere, even if you think there isn't one.

Comment: @Olesya If you just want to know why the Session value appears in the error output we would need to see the definition of `Temple_sp_Application_Insert` added to the question. *Removed original comment because [OP changed their comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748533/sql-server-error-executing-sql-stored-procedure-in-asp-classic-microsoftsql-s/40748669?noredirect=1#comment68723293_40748669) before the cut off*

Comment: thank you for the hint about the stored procedure itself. That  session variable, was indeed the Print statement that was no commented out in the procedure script. I have removed it, and now I can see the actual error message. The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'deposit', database 'intr_DB', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: @Olesya so there is a permission issue with `dbo.deposit` object. Rule of thumb: always trust error codes. If you had posted the definition of the Stored Procedure we could have had this sorted quicker, may be something for next time.